# Why is v-for can't show the value with computed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

This is for select a `city` and `area`, It will filter the same data to show it. But I meet with a problem is that when I selected, the value doesn't appear.

I have been try and searched similar code but still doesn't find the solution.

This is the image when of HTML rendering **:**

[image]

Here is template **:**

```html
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="(live , idx) of filterLivingNames" :key="idx">
    <h3 class="text-center">{{live.Name}}</h3>
    <p>Address：</p>
    <p>Phone：</p>
</a>
```

Here is script

```js
import LivingData from '@/assets/LivingData.json';

export default {
    computed: {
        livedata(){
            return LivingData;
        },

        filterLivingNames(){
            let livelength = this.livedata.length

            for(let i = 0 ; i < livelength ; i++){
                if(this.livedata[i].Region === this.city && this.livedata[i].Town === this.area){
                    console.log(this.livedata[i])
                    return this.livedata[i]
                }
                else{
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update json file

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "Hotel-1",
    "Region": "Region-1",
    "Town": "Town-1",
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "Hotel-2",
    "Region": "Region-2",
    "Town": "Town-2",
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Name": "Hotel-3",
    "Region": "Region-2",
    "Town": "Town-1",
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Name": "Hotel-4",
    "Region": "Region-1",
    "Town": "Town-2",
  },
]
```

Comment: filterLivingNames doesn't seem to return an array, it returns an object and it doesn't return anything if you don't find any results in your for loop.

Comment: Use .filter if you want to return multiple items

Comment: But when I use console,I can see string,address...etc inside

Comment: Isn't filter remove in vue3?

Comment: Can you share the `LivingData.json` contents ?

Comment: OK I update in edit

Comment: Ezycod：I understand what you means, thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are filtering out the `livedata` based on `Region` and `Town`. You can simply use the [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and this will resolve the issue you are facing as it will return the array.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    livedata: [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Hotel-1",
        "Region": "Region-1",
        "Town": "Town-1",
      },
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Hotel-2",
        "Region": "Region-2",
        "Town": "Town-2",
      },
      {
        "Id": "3",
        "Name": "Hotel-3",
        "Region": "Region-2",
        "Town": "Town-1",
      },
      {
        "Id": "4",
        "Name": "Hotel-4",
        "Region": "Region-1",
        "Town": "Town-2",
      }
    ],
    city: 'Region-1',
    area: 'Town-1'
  },
  computed: {
    filterLivingNames() {
      return this.livedata.filter(obj => obj.Region === this.city && obj.Town === this.area)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="(livingData, index) of filterLivingNames" :key="index">
    <h3 class="text-center">{{ livingData.Name }}</h3>
    <p>Address：</p>
    <p>Phone：</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It can work by this way. But I still confused about my original way doesn't work, beacuse it wasn't return an array?

Comment: @Joseph1997520 Yes, for objects you have to use `for...in` instead of `for...of`. i.e. `v-for="live in filterLivingNames"`

Comment: Your answer make me clicked, thanks again!!